# Как обойти или добавить ввод капчи для бота, который будет анализировать тп steam?

Tags: python, steam, captcha

У меня есть бот, но при попытке авторизации приходит отказ из-за того, что я не ввел капчу.
Бот написан на python и библиотеке steampy.

Вопрос заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как принять капчу со steam и дальше ее решить. В приоритете все таки ручной ввод ибо он бесплатный и выполняется только при запуске. И капчи разные у стима, но все связаны с выбором велосипедов и тд.

```
import time
from steampy.client import SteamClient, Asset
from steampy.utils import GameOptions
from steampy.market import SteamMarket as Market

# API ключ для доступа к Steam
API_KEY = 'API_KEY'

# Идентификатор игры и валюты
APP_ID = 730
CURRENCY = 'RUB'

# Минимальный процент прибыли
MIN_PROFIT = 5.0

# Максимальная стоимость предмета
MAX_ITEM_PRICE = 1000.0

# Alert сообщение, которое будет отправлено при удачной сделке
ALERT_MESSAGE = "Buying item: {0} for {1} with expected profit {2}%"

# Создаем экземпляр SteamClient и авторизуемся
SG_FILE_PATH = 'steamguard_file.json'

steam_client = SteamClient(API_KEY)
steam_client.login('username', 'password', SG_FILE_PATH)  # Замените 'username' и 'password' и 'steamguard' на свои данные для входа в аккаунт.

# Остальной код...
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\steambot\bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    steam_client.login('****', '*****', SG_FILE_PATH)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\steampy\client.py", line 46, in login
    LoginExecutor(username, password, self.steam_guard['shared_secret'], self._session).login()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\steampy\login.py", line 21, in login
    self._check_for_captcha(login_response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\steampy\login.py", line 87, in _check_for_captcha
    raise CaptchaRequired('Captcha required')
steampy.exceptions.CaptchaRequired: Captcha required
```

Comment: Вам нужно принять капчу и ввести её, либо перевести на сервис распознавания капчи, при этом на всякий случай обрабатывать ошибку с помощью try-except. Чем вам помочь - не ясно